# How to make this background image a smooth animation

Tags: css

How can this be made to make a seamless animation? As of right now it jumps during part of the animation.

[JSFIDDLE (Chrome)](http://jsfiddle.net/42zYP/)

```
.poster
{
width: 178px;
height: 257px;
background-color: #212121;
background-size: 100px 100px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .05) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
-webkit-animation: backgroundmove infinite 2s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundmove {
from {
    background-position: left;
}

to {
    background-position: right;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your animation values to:

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundmove {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }

    to {
        background-position: 0 100px;
    }
}
```

Fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/tehtrav/Pcn5w/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the geometry of your image. The animation takes the background from right to left, using a certain duration. That means the left-most pixel moves a certain distance to the right over that length of time (2s), and then the animation is repeated, left to right. If the moment just before the repeat does not visually mimic the moment just after the animation restarts, you'll see the jump.

I removed the jump by modifying the `background-size` property, here http://jsfiddle.net/42zYP/1/

You can see the jump become more pronounced as you modify the `background-size` more and more.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/42zYP/5/)**

```
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundmove {
    from { background-position: 0;     }
    to   { background-position: 100px; }
}
```